# v-model implementation via render function is not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to create dynamic input component that will be interchangeable between input and textarea tag. I am trying to implement this by using render function. (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#v-model).

The problem I have is that v-model works only one way, if I change data property directly it updates textarea value, but if I change or input new data into textarea it does not update the data property. Does anyone know how to make it work both ways?
Here is my code link for code pen is bellow it illustrates the problem:

```
const tag = Vue.component('dynamic-tag', {
    name: 'dynamic-tag',
    render(createElement) {
        return createElement(
            this.tag,
            {
                domProps: {
                    value: this.value
                },
                on: {
                    input: event => {
                        this.value = event.target.value
                    }
                }
            },
            this.$slots.default
        )
    },
    props: {
        tag: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: ''
  },
  components: {tag}
})
```

http://codepen.io/asolopovas/pen/OpWVxa?editors=1011

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `$emit` changes from your input.

```
on: {
    input: event => {
        this.value = event.target.value
        this.$emit('input', event.target.value)
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndriusSolopovas I agree, the documentation seems to gloss over this point.

Comment: where's pointing `this` context in your case? I just tried it with TS, besides i got types error, it doesn't work at all. Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: @AlexanderKim That depends on how you defined your render function. If you did so as shown in the question, it will be the Vue component. If your render function is an arrow function, then its probably not working.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using v-model with a custom component.
When using with component `v-model="message"` is just syntactic sugar for

```
v-bind:value="message"
v-on:input="value => { message = value }"
```

So to use v-model with custom component, your component must have `value` prop and emit input event with the changed value.

I will leave further explanations to the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events)

Comment: I know how to implement v-model for custom components by emitting input from a custom component with a value, the problem is it spams my vue-devtools with a huge amount of emits I thought I could implement it quietly in a pragmatic way. So that it sort of works like native v-model, and to be honest if render function implement v-for and the rest of the attributes there should be a way of implementing the complete v-model.